# Facing ANR issue in google play services 7.5.0

Tags: android, multithreading, google-analytics

This is my local class where I initialize the tracker instance and also google analytics.

```
public class Analytics     
{
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleAnalytics mAnalytics;
    private Tracker mTracker;
    public static boolean analytics_enabled = false;
    public static int lastTabStripPositionValue = -1;
    private SharedPreferences sPrefs;

    public Analytics(Context context, String screenName) 
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext);
        mAnalytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
        sPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mTracker = mAnalytics.newTracker(mContext.getString(R.string.analyticsAppTrackingId));
        int consumer_id =sPrefs.getInt(context.getString(R.string.consumer_id),-1);
        //sets the user id with this instance of tracker object.
        if(consumer_id!=-1)
        {
            mTracker.set("&uid",consumer_id+"");
        }
        mTracker.setScreenName(screenName);
        //mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        mTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(false);
    }

    public GoogleAnalytics getGoogleAnalyticsInstance() 
    {
        return mAnalytics;
    }

    public Tracker getTrackerInstance() 
    {
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

And I intialize the tracker instance inside onCreate() method of respective activities.

```
analytics = new Analytics(this, getString(R.string.D_L_Activity));
    t = analytics.getTrackerInstance();
```

My app works fine in most case but sometimes it gets into the ANR state. The following image[image](extracted from the ANR report) seems to provide the root cause. I am unable to get the problem behind it so kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding the actual codeline that stalls:** Put `Log.e`s everywhere.

**Workaround/Maybe actually right way to do this:** Instead of directly initialising the analytics in onCreate, start a new thread, which initialises it with callback for when it's done, and only do related things when that callback arrives.

Code snippet to init() in new thread:

```
activity{ //beware pseudo-code for not important stuff

    onCreate(Stuff stuff){
    yourOtherStuff();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                analytics = new Analytics(this, getString(R.string.D_L_Activity));
                t = analytics.getTrackerInstance();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printstacktrace();
            }
            //if no exception occured (or you didn't get it because analytics handled it itself)
            callBack();
        }  
    }.start();
    }

    private void callBack(){
    new Handler().post(doStuffWhenAnalyticsIsInitialized);
    }

    Runnable doStuffWhenAnalyticsIsInitialized = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            doYourStuffHere();
        }    
    };
}
```

Comment: Ok will try the workaround logic and see if that works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I get this ANR as ANR report in google analytics web page. While using the app i don't generally get it, so putting Log.e won't be much of a use i guess.

Comment: Then try to catch that exception mentioned in the report and print it's stacktrace to your logcat. Unless of course the workaround works well.

Comment: So if inside the thread the exception occurred, then will it crash my app?

Comment: As far as i know it will only crash the respective thread, until of course you try to access that thread from the main thread. Although it's puzzling anyway that you get an ANR from analytics, as i thought it works in a background thread and those usually don't get ANRs; on the contrary, they are the solution to ANRs.

Comment: Yes, it is puzzling. Also the thing is I get this ANR problem rarely, but still I need to somehow find a solution. Can you provide a code snippet of running this initialization process of tracker instance in a separate thread and if the thread processes the task perfectly then getting this tracker instance to do further task.

Comment: Added the code snippet, may be optimized and adapted for your needs :)  
Maybe you can still put `Log.e`s in your analytics code, so you may trigger an exception where it would actually not trigger because it's already handled by google internally. But if you "use" everything initialized in there (by calling toString() on it from the Log.e), you may get that exception.